# Issues with theme integration in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I am facing odd issues while trying to integrate a premium theme with Blazor Server Side.

All paths have been updated like this example `<script src="~/pages/js/pages.js"></script>` and components are being rendered properly, however the JS events which should have been triggered upon change of screen-size are not being fired. There is no error on the console aswell.

One thing I noticed is that after my `@Body` ends, the `_Host.cshtml` file/process ends immediately afterwards.

The order for the files to be executed and ended should have been this:

[image: How the flow should have been]

But this is the order I am getting:

[image: Order I am getting]

Comment: Blazor abstracts the DOM manipulations and events from you into its own ShadowDOM so you don't touch the DOM directly. I am not familiar with the themes and code you use, but it looks like they rely on JS to get events like `window.resize` and to touch the DOM. In Blazor you need to call a C# method then, instead of touching the DOM, and in that method do your work (e.g., propagate the event through a service). You can see ready-made packages for this like this one https://github.com/EdCharbeneau/BlazorSize

Comment: I understand, does this mean that the events being added in the theme are not working? I then have to manually write C# code for that, which completely kills the concept of working with a theme.

Comment: Probably. As I said, I am not sure what themes you are talking about, what they do and what they provide, so take what I say with a grain of salt.